# Least manual labour algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently searching for an appropriate algorithm for the following problem.

The warehouse contains a bunch of pallets with boxes on them containing the same product.
A full pallet contains 80 boxes. But there are a lot of pallets with less boxes.
When the orders come in, some pallets need to be merged into one full pallet of 80 boxes. This action is done by hand so this is manual labour.

Now I'm looking for the optimal way to assign the pallets in the warehouse to the orders so that the amount of manual labour is reduced to the minimum.

**example:**

1. Pallet A: 80 boxes
2. Pallet B: 40 boxes
3. Pallet C: 39 boxes

- order 1: 50 boxes
- order 2: 79 boxes

**possible solutions**

- order 1: pallet A - 30 boxes
- order 2: pallet B + pallet C

=> total manual labour: 69 boxes moved

- order 1: pallet B + 10 boxes from pallet C
- order 2: pallet A - 1 box

=> total manual labour: 11 boxes moved

The second solution is preferred because less labour is involved.

I had a look at the Hungarian algorithm, but I think that this is not the appropriate solution for this problem.

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Could you give an example of the input to the algorithm and the expected output? It's not clear to me what the algorithm actually needs to do.

Comment: I have updated the question with a practical example

Comment: How many pallets can there be, roughly?

Comment: Could we move only 10 boxes by moving 1 box from A to B and 9 boxes from C to B?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: there will be around 100 pallets maximum.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat this third solution is also possible and is the most preferred one because it involves even less labour.

Comment: I was thinking about an alternate solution. You fill the pallets, so there likely is a pallet ready for every order size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hungarian algorithm gives a 2-approximation (move at most twice as many boxes as needed). We match pallets to orders, where the cost of matching a pallet with an order is half the number of boxes that need to move onto or off of the pallet. (I gather that there will typically be more pallets than orders, so if your Hungarian algorithm implementation requires a square matrix, make fake orders that have zero cost to match with any pallet.) This is a 2-approximation because, to extend the observation from my comment, we save a box only if we can find both a pallet with too many boxes and a pallet with too few.

In other words, we pay the max of (the number of boxes that need to move off of a pallet) and (the number of boxes that need to move onto a pallet). This observation motivates the following two ideas.

1. We can formulate a mixed integer program (and then apply a solver library). There is a 0–1 variable x(i, j) for each pallet i and order j. We have constraints sum over i of x(i, j) = 1 (all orders have exactly one assigned pallet) and sum over j of x(i, j) ≤ 1 (all pallets have at most one assigned order). The objective to be minimized is a free variable z, where we constrain z ≥ sum over i, j of max(p(i) − o(j), 0) x(i, j); and z ≥ sum over i, j of max(o(j) − p(i), 0) x(i, j).
2. If you don’t want to do mixed integer programming for whatever reason (despite the fact that I think you really should), we can use a Lagrangian dual, introducing a parameter α ∈ [0, 1] and paying 1−α to move a box off of an order pallet and α to move a box onto an order pallet. The easy way to do this is to try a bunch of different α with the Hungarian algorithm, taking the best matching that results. The clever way is to solve the dual of the linear relaxation of the integer program above, then set α according to the dual variables corresponding to the constraints on z. But really you should use mixed integer programming.

I can give advice on solvers if you tell me your constraints.

Comment: P.S. you didn't mention if it's more effort to move a box between more distant pallets, but in principle that could be taken into account if you asked a new question.

Comment: I think you pointed me in the right direction. But it is unclear to me how to fill the initial matrix to start the Hungarian algorithm. Must I fill in the 'score' that describes the match between the order and the pallet? So in my sample above pallet C with 79 boxes has a higher score for order 2 of 80 boxes than pallets B and C. If so than how can this solution tell me which pallets to combine rather than only tell me what the best pallet is to start with to complete the order?

Comment: @awmoeder Yes, you fill in the scores. Once you know which order is using which pallet, you move boxes from the over-full pallets to the under-full pallets while you can, then finish the job with moves where one of the pallets involved has no assigned order.

Comment: Alright, that is a neat solution. About your remark about the distance between the pallets. How can I take this into account. Or is this a complete new problem that I should resolve while moving the boxes from the over-full pallets to the under-full pallets?

Comment: @awmoeder You could solve it that way using Earth Mover's Distance, but depending on the fixed versus variable cost of moving a box, it might be significantly better to take distances into account while assigning pallets, which is a new question because it disrupts the structure that this answer exploits. There's also tiliavirga's suggestion of trying to optimize efficiency over time rather than for the given set of orders.